# Parsing stringify string in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I do have string

```
{"version":"T2"}
```

I was reading it from webview and storing it in variable **s**. 
I want to parse the value of version. So

```
   try {
         s= s.replaceAll("\n", "\\n");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
        Log.d("SAVE_LOG", (String) json.get("version"));
       } catch (JSONException e) {
         Log.d("SAVE_LOG", String.valueOf(e));
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

I found this code from every site. 
But it is giving me this error.

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"version":"T2"} of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

My imports are

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tcn.liftboard.control.PayMethod;
import com.tcn.liftboard.control.TcnVendEventID;
import com.tcn.liftboard.control.TcnVendEventResultID;
import com.tcn.liftboard.control.TcnVendIF;
import com.tcn.liftboard.control.VendEventInfo;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;
```

Comment: What are your imports? In my machine, it work very fine!

Comment: @YCF_L updated with imports

Comment: In my case I import just `import org.json.JSONException; import org.json.JSONObject;` as you do, and it works very fine, I would suggest also to check the version of your library, json library

Comment: @YCF_L i can you please tell how can i c that ?

Comment: just use the last version and see what is the result https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: @YCF_L Android studio is auto importing it I dont know how can i update that :-) can you please tell ?

Comment: Not the down-voter here, but I'm sorry, I'm not an android developer, so I can't help you more than this :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
             String s = "{\"version\":\"T2\"}";
             s= s.replaceAll("\n", "\\n");
             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("version"));
           } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

}
```

Output :

```
T2
```

Import json jar file from [JSON jar download from maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

Comment: Thanku. Can not try now. And i did solve problem with different approach.